# Phase 10 “Skip” Card

Tags: phase-10

Just read a rule concerning “Skip” card. You place the Skip card in front of player skipping. My question is, does next player have option of taking previous discard?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [rules at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_10), the Skip card is placed in the discard, not in front of the skipped player. Those rules also prohibit the drawing of a skip card from the discard pile. (So: no, the next player does not have the option of taking the previous card from the discard pile. Only the top card can be drawn, and the Skip card being on top precludes that.)

> To use, a player discards the "Skip" card on their turn and chooses the player who will lose a turn.

> A "Skip" card may never be picked up from the discard pile.

These rules match the rules given at the [unorules Phase 10 page](https://www.unorules.com/phase-10-rules/).

Comment: [Related](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/53913/skip-card-points-count-against-you). There appears to be at least one version of Phase 10 Rules which describe putting the Skip Card in front of another player instead of the discard.

Comment: @GendoIkari yeah, I readily believe there exist rules that are divergent from the rules linked in my answer in that manner. But without a reference to the ruleset in question, it is difficult to ascertain how that divergent ruleset resolves this issue. I searched for combinations of words I could think of that might yield a link to such rules, but came up empty.

Comment: FWIW, The phrasing quoted in that related post: "chosen to skip instead of placing it on the discard pile" occurs nowhere else in Google's search results -- Google only returns that question.

Comment: I also found it in the rules for Phase 10 Twist: https://www.ultraboardgames.com/phase-10/twist.php

Comment: "also"? But sure, there are other games that might have that rule. But Phase 10 Twist is not Phase 10 (for instance, it has 3 discard piles instead of 1, so the question of "taking the previous discard" isn't going to come up, at least not formulated that way).